# Custom AuditorAware getCurrentAuditor with @MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I am attempting to load a customized value into the `@CreatedBy` field in my `AuditFields` entity. Whenever I make a `POST` request, I am expecting Spring Data Rest to use this `AuditorAwareImpl` and pass the `TestPrincipal` string to the `@CreatedBy` field.

The result I am actually getting is `409 Conflict, SQL Constraint created_by is null`.

The `BaseEntity` needs to use `@MappedSuperclass` but I think it needs the functionality of `@Entity` in order to pass the value through to `@CreatedBy`?

Any pointers here would be greatly appreciated.

**AuditEntity**

```java
@Embeddable
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Data
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class AuditFields implements Serializable {

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name="CREATED_BY", length=256)
    private String createdBy; 

    @Column(name="CREATED_TIMESTAMP")
    private LocalDateTime createTimestamp = LocalDateTime.now();

    ...
    ...

}
```

**BaseEntity**

```java
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="RECORD_STATUS_CODE", length=1)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private String myStatus;

    @Version
    @Column(name="VERSION_NUMBER")
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Long versionNumber;

    @Embedded
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private AuditEntity auditFields;
}
```

**AuditorAwareImpl**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider")
public class AuditorAwareImpl {

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {
        return new AuditorAware<String>() {
            @Override
            public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
                return Optional.of("TestPrincipal");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is that `@CreatedBy` doesn't work in an `@Embedded` entity without some extra work.

I pieced together a few different tutorials, the result being that I put the `@EntityListener` in my `MyEntity` and wrote a custom listener class that uses `@PrePost`. You can then build it out more by adding a `BaseEntity` that embeds the `AuditEntity`, etc.

**AuditEntity**

```java
@Embeddable
@Data
public class AuditEntity {
    @Column(name="CREATED_BY")
    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    // additional fields ...

}
```

**MyEntity**

```java
@Data
@Table(name="TABLENAME", schema="SCHEMANAME")
@EntityListeners(CustomAuditListener.class)
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="MY_ID")
    private Long myId;

    @Embedded
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private AuditEntity auditFields;
}
```

**CustomAuditListener**

```java
public class CustomAuditListener {
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(Object obj) {
        MyEntity entity = (MyEntity) obj;
        AuditFields audit = new AuditFields();
        audit.setCreatedBy("CreatedByValueHere")        
        entity.setAuditFields(audit);
    }

    // can add @PreUpdate, etc, here  

}
```